# Hackerrank: Pilling Up! challenge

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've came up with solution to the [Piling Up!](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/piling-up/) problem on HackerRank. It passes all tests on HackerRank. How could I improve this code? Are there any cases outside those provided on HR that I've missed?

```
for _ in (range(int(input()))):
    no_of_cubes = int(input())
    side_lengths = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
    result = "Yes"
    if max(side_lengths) not in (side_lengths[0], side_lengths[-1]):
        result = "No"
    print(result)
```

Comment: Tests as in the two test cases in the problem page, or tests as in the submission passes?

Comment: Unless I overlooking something, your solution is wrong: It would not detect that `3 2 1 2 1` can *not* be piled.

Comment: @vnp all tests as in the submission passes.

Comment: @MartinR my question was to prove my solution wrong, and thank you for sharing that answer with me!

Can anyone explain it to me why is the question put on hold, so I know it fo future reference?

Comment: I am asking for feedback on `Correctness in unanticipated cases` which seems to be under list of areas that are allowed by Code review Stack Exchange.

Comment: This question was originally closed as broken, as there is a comment showing an input for which it returns an incorrect answer.  It should probably be reopened for that, as it's an edge case and fixing the code would probably invalidate the answer.  However, the question is still *Unclear what you're asking*.  You hide what the code does behind a link.  The general rule is to restate, summarize, or quote the problem statement in the question itself.  It's a bit confusing in that the question has close votes for at least three different reasons but only one is listed.

Comment: @mdfst13: You are right about a possible answer invalidation, but I would not call that an "edge case", the solution is just wrong.

Comment: @an0o0nym: Did you *submit* your solution to HR and it passed all tests?

Comment: @MartinR Yes I did submit my solution to HR and it passed all tests as I wrote it in the question.

Comment: @mdfst13 This question was originally closed as broken, as there is a comment showing an input for which it returns an incorrect answer. -  but that was the main reason for asking this question - to find out if there is a case where my solution doesn't work, as it was surprising for me that this code passed all tests on HR.

Comment: my [Piling Up](https://github.com/Grijesh-Chauhan/Hackerrank/blob/master/PilingUp/piliing_up.py) passes all tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> Are there any cases outside those provided on HR that I've missed?

Indeed, there are, and the "simplest" one is `2 1 2 1`: Your code
checks that the maximum side length is equal to the first or last
number in the array, and prints "Yes".

But actually this row can *not* be stacked:  The first cube with
side length 2 must be picked first, then the two cubes with length
1 in any order.
That leaves us with a cube with length 2 which cannot be stacked on top of the others.

How can this be fixed? If the given side length are
$$
 a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_n
$$
then your code checks if
$$
 \max_i a_i \in \{ a_1, a_n \}
$$
which is a necessary condition, but not sufficient.

Let us first assume that the row of cubes *can* be stacked,
and let \$ m \$ be the index of the cube which is chosen *last*
(\$ 1 \le m \le n \$). Then it is clear that
$$ \tag{*}
 a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \ldots \ge a_m \le a_{m+1} \le \ldots \le a_{n-1} \le a_n \, ,
$$
i.e. the side length are first decreasing, and then increasing.

So \$(*) \$ is a *necessary* condition for the row to be stackable.
But it is also *sufficent:* If   \$(*) \$  is satisfied then the two
decreasing sequences
$$
 a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \ldots \ge a_m \\
 a_n \ge a_{n-1} \ge \ldots \ge a_{m+1}
$$
can be merged into a single decreasing sequence by choosing (and removing) the larger of the two front elements until both sequences
are exhausted.

Therefore a row can be stacked exactly if the
side length are of the form \$(*) \$, this can be checked with a single
traversal of the list. I'll leave the implementation in Python up to you :)

Comment: Just one question, why there is an≥an−1≥…≥ **am−1** ?

Comment: @an0o0nym: \$ a_{n-1} \$ is picked *after* \$ a_n \$, therefore \$ a_{n-1} \le a_n \$.

Comment: yes, I got that part, but I was talking about the am-1(not an-1) in last equation of your answer.

Comment: @an0o0nym: That was a typo, sorry!

Comment: That what I suspected, now it all makes sense. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That was a fun little challenge to code against, although my solution was [very different](https://pastebin.com/tB6pVLaY) from yours!

With those kinds of challenges, it can be tempting to just write throw-away code. I would suggest though, if you are serious about coding, to just try to write the most professional code you can, even if it's just to solve this one challenge.

---

In particular, I find your code is not very expressive. There's no functions/methods/classes, there's really not anything telling me (or future you) what this code is for at all, so I'm having to actually read the code from beginning to end to even get an idea what it's supposed to do (let alone if it's doing it correctly). This also makes it much less reusable.

---

We can start by organizing input handling separately from program logic. In fact, I think `__main__` would be a perfect place to handle getting input. You'll notice my code is somewhat more verbose, I personally prefer to make it obvious when doing "breaky" things like reading raw text input.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_cases = int(input())
    for case in range(num_cases):
        no_of_cubes = int(input())
        side_lengths = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
```

I don't think it would be unreasonable to create a function to handle text input, but that may be a bit much for this. So, we have our input, now we just need to handle it.

---

One data structure to consider, and for which it seems like this challenge was written, is the [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects)...

> Deques are a generalization of stacks and queues (the name is pronounced “deck” and is short for “double-ended queue”). Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction.

However, you found a shorter, less literal way to pass the test cases, which, in the end, is the goal. So if you wanted to keep it at that, I'd just move the logic into a function and return a `bool`, and call it a day.

```
def can_be_piled(no_of_cubes: int, side_lengths: List) -> bool:
    if max(side_lengths) not in (side_lengths[0], side_lengths[-1]):
        return False
    return True
```

I also made a few other utility functions, one to split up the side lengths, the other to display the output. Note that I used [Python 3 type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) in each function signature, in case that looks unfamiliar.

```
from typing import List

def can_be_piled(no_of_cubes: int, side_lengths: List) -> bool:
    if max(side_lengths) not in (side_lengths[0], side_lengths[-1]):
        return False
    return True

def get_side_lengths(raw_input: str) -> List:
    return list(map(int, raw_input.strip().split()))

def display_output(truthy: bool) -> None:
    if truthy:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_cases = int(input())
    for case in range(num_cases):
        no_of_cubes = int(input())
        side_lengths = get_side_lengths(input())
        display_output(can_be_piled(no_of_cubes, side_lengths))
```

Comment: That was a lot of time and effor you put into that answer, I found it very helpful! Thank you for your review.

Comment: You can turn `display_output` function a one liner: `print("Yes") if truthy else print("No")`.

Comment: Same for `can_be_piled`: `return max(side_lengths) in (side_lengths[0], side_lengths[-1])`.